# Was Martin Gardner's Purple Hat Club a real nightclub (or based on a real club)?

Tags: martin-gardner

Martin Gardner's finest piece of fiction was almost certainly "[The No-Sided Professor](http://electronictiger.net/sided.pdf)."  He named his 1987 collection of "complete" short fiction after it (although he notes, for reasons partially preserved at the top of first scanned page in the above link, that the collection does not actually include the sequel story, "The Five-Color Island").  And although many of Gardner's stories were about scientists, especially mathematicians, only a few, including the "The No-Sided Professor," were really science fiction or fantasy.

The setting of "The No-Sided Professor" is the Purple Hat Club in Chicago.  (In 1947, when the story was first published in *[Esquire](http://archive.esquire.com/issue/19470101)*, it was apparently considered acceptable for mathematicians to hold professional meetings at strip joints.)  The club also appears in quite a few of Gardner's other stories, although rarely so prominently.  (In the 1946 story "The Horse on the Escalator," a story narrated by an emcee at the club who was based on Gardner's friend Werner Dornfield, the Purple Hat is describe as being "in the uptown area of Chicago's north side.")

I have sort of wondered, since I read Gardner's 1987 collection of fiction, whether it was a real club.  Google does not seem to find any evidence of it, but most of those stories were written more than half a century ago.  So, was it a real nightclub, and if not, was it based on a real club (in Chicago, or even possibly elsewhere)?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. He seemed very familiar with Chicago nightclub culture, I think some of the Dr. Matrix stories are set there as well.  Maybe it comes from his background in magic. I hope someone can answer.